# If every real valued differentiable function on $X \subset \mathbb R^n$ is bounded , then is it true that $X$ is compact ?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, metric-spaces, compactness

If every real valued differentiable function on $X \subset \mathbb R^n$ is bounded , then is it true that $X$ is compact ?

Comment: If $X$ is made of isolated points it looks like the set of differentiable functions on $X$ is empty, hence there's not much you can say about $X$ in this case. Or perhaps you mean differentiable in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and bounded when restricted to $X$..

Comment: @Giovanni: more generally, should X be connected also?

Comment: @Groups: I don't think connectedness is what I was concerned about, it is more having accumulation point to be able to take derivatives. The reason for this is that it is not clear to me if the function we are differentiating are defined on $X$ or if we want to look at the restriction to $X$ of differentiable maps on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is true. Hint: The functions $f(x) = \| x\|^2$ and $g_a(x) = \| x-a\|^{-2}$ are smooth (in the second case only for $a \notin X$, of course.)

Comment: @@LukasNothing is clear to me. Can you give more detail ?

Comment: @S717717: If $X$ is unbounded, then $f$ is unbounded on $X$. If $X$ is not closed, then there is a point $a \in \partial X \setminus X$ for which $g_a$ is unbounded. Together this implies that $X$ is bounded and closed, so it is compact.

Comment: Suppose not closed then there is a limit point a outside X take the function 1/<x-a, x-a> 
Suppose not bounded take the function f(x) =<x,x>. Take in this form because of Rⁿ. Hope it will work. same as Lukas ans.